# Amazon S3 client based on SOAP

Tags: soap, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

I need a Win client for Amazon S3  that utilizes SOAP protocol for all transactions. As far as I see most solutions are REST based rather than SOAP. Any ideas?

EDIT:

Just want to clarify: please do not suggest using REST instead. I am perfectly aware of what can or cannot be done with either protocol. So if I ask for this specific solution, there is a reason for that.

What I need is a working software for Win platform that utilizes SOAP for Amazon S3, not suggestions how to do my job. Thank you.

Comment: Why do you need SOAP? S3's REST API is _much_ simpler, and I believe SOAP is missing some functionality...

Comment: I agree. SOAP should be the last resort.

Comment: Building a small app that utilizes SOAP. Need a comparable working solution.

Comment: which technology are you using for your windows client?

Comment: @Nick, can't you use one of the existing REST libraries for S3, and SOAP for whatever else you're doing?

Comment: I need a fully working application, not a component to integrate with. Our app is a very small piece of the product which was built from scratch.

Comment: @bdonlan If I could, why would I ask this question in the first place?

Comment: @Nick, it's not uncommon for someone to ask a question about how to do things the hard way, when there is an easier way. If you really do have to do things the hard way (SOAP), though, that's something different.

Comment: Why do you people think that the SOAP API is harder to use? Do you think he's going to have to create the XML by hand?

Answer (score 3):

1. Start Visual Studio 2008, create a new C# Windows console application.
2. Add the S3 WSDL as a service reference. In Solution Explorer, right click References, select Add Service Reference. Type in the S3 WSDL address in the Address box: http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/AmazonS3.wsdl. Click Go. "AmazonS3" should show in the Services box. Enter a namespace. I entered Amazon.S3. Click OK.
3. Modify Program.cs to look something like the following:

---

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Text;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using ConsoleApplication1.Amazon.S3;

namespace ConsoleApplication1 {
    class Program {
        private const string accessKeyId     = "YOURACCESSKEYIDHERE0";
        private const string secretAccessKey = "YOURSECRETACCESSKEYHEREANDYESITSTHATLONG";

        public static DateTime LocalNow() {
            DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
            return new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, now.Day, now.Hour, now.Minute, now.Second, now.Millisecond, DateTimeKind.Local);
        }

       public static string SignRequest(string secret, string operation, DateTime timestamp) {
            HMACSHA1 hmac         = new HMACSHA1(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(secret));
            string   isoTimeStamp = timestamp.ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            string   signMe       = "AmazonS3" + operation + isoTimeStamp;
            string   signature    = Convert.ToBase64String(hmac.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(signMe)));
            return signature;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args) {
            DateTime       now    = LocalNow();
            AmazonS3Client client = new AmazonS3Client();

            var result = client.ListAllMyBuckets(
                accessKeyId,
                now,
                SignRequest(secretAccessKey, "ListAllMyBuckets", now));

            foreach (var bucket in result.Buckets) {
                Console.WriteLine(bucket.Name);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you now insert your access key ID and secret access key in the appropriate spots and run the program, you should get a listing of your S3 buckets.

The AmazonS3Client class has all the SOAP operations available as instance methods on it.

The Amazon website carries an older (VS2005 + WSE) C#/SOAP sample at http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/entry.jspa?externalID=129&categoryID=47.

EDIT: posted a visual studio solution at http://flyingpies.wordpress.com/2009/08/04/the-shortest-ever-s3-csoapwcf-client/.